# Обтекание двумя блоками

Tags: html, css

Задача: сделать блок, обтекаемый другими блоками. В 2 - только текст, с ним все в порядке. В 3 - маркированный список.
Проблема 1. Блок 1 обтекается только блоком 2. Даже если 2 и 3 объединять в один контейнер. Как я понимаю, дело в содержимом, нужны строчные элементы. Есть ли способы решения?
Проблема 2. Как задать ширину, чтобы 1 и 2 оставались в середине, а 3 тянулся на весь экран. При объединении 2 и 3 блок 3 сужается. Без этого блок 1 уезжает, как ему и положено.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для простоты сделала схематичный код

```css
main {
  width: 1100px;
}
div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.first {
  width: 300px;
  float: right;
}

.second {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
}

.three {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1e77a2;
}

.four {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  min-width: 320px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="first">1
  </div>
    <div class="second">
     <p>Куча текста</p>
    <p>Куча текста</p>
    <p>Куча текста</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo ut ab aliquam doloremque distinctio delectus corrupti voluptate quas recusandae, neque obcaecati provident itaque ex a similique quidem assumenda fugiat veritatis! Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo ut ab aliquam doloremque distinctio delectus corrupti voluptate quas recusandae, neque obcaecati provident itaque ex a similique quidem assumenda fugiat veritatis!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="three">
      <div class="four">
      4
     </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

Решила вопрос, добавив флоату родительской блок и навесив overflow:hidden на блок 2

Comment: Слова у разных людей понимаются по разному. Лучше скопировать в ответ ваш код, ведь вы пишете, что решили задачу. Уверен, что сразу получите больше плюсов.